# Export to PDF using rmarkdown render without PDF navigation buttons

Tags: r, pdf, render, r-markdown

I am using the `render` function from `rmarkdown` to export a .Rmd file to PDF.

The .Rmd file is the template generated within RStudio using

New File > R Markdown > Presentation > PDF (Beamer)

When export to PDF, each PDF page has navigation buttons at the bottom of the page which I would like to exclude during the export process. Below are the buttons.

[image]

Does anyone know how to exclude these navigation buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a command to turn them off in your header:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: beamer_presentation
header-includes:
 - \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
---
```